# Database backend error in django for foreign key

Tags: python, django

I am unable to run command runserver in my django app.
It always show:
You have unapplied migrations; your app may not work properly until they are applied.
Run 'python manage.py migrate' to apply them.

And when i am trying to migrate it will show this error:
raise ValueError('The database backend does not accept 0 as a ' ValueError: The database backend does not accept 0 as a value for AutoField.

And this is the code in my models.py

```
class Category(models.Model):
    category_name = models.CharField(max_length=128, unique=True)
    category_alias = models.CharField(max_length=128, unique=True)
    category_desc = models.TextField()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.category_name

class Question(models.Model):
    #user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category)
    question_text = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    pub_date = models.DateTimeField('date published')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.question_text

class Answer(models.Model):
    question = models.ForeignKey(Question)
    answer = models.TextField()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.answer

class UserProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User)

    state = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True)
    country = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True)
    zipcode = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.user.username
```

Can someone help me to come out of it.

Code in file 0003_question_user.py:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from __future__ import unicode_literals

from django.db import models, migrations
from django.conf import settings


class Migration(migrations.Migration):

    dependencies = [
        migrations.swappable_dependency(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL),
        ('confession', '0002_userprofile'),
    ]

    operations = [
        migrations.AddField(
            model_name='question',
            name='user',
            field=models.ForeignKey(default=0,         to=settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL),
            preserve_default=False,
        ),
    ]
```

Comment: You don't seem to have posted the code for the failing migration.

Comment: About which code you are asking? Now i have posted the error message too.

Comment: Well, it's failing on migration 0003_question_user in the confession app. What does that migration actually look like?

Comment: when i am trying to run this command "python manage.py sqlmigrate confession 0003" It is throwing the same error.

Comment: I didn't ask that. I asked you *what the code for that migration looks like*. We can't help you without seeing it.

Comment: Actually this error comes when i am trying to add another field i.e user in Question model:   user = models.ForeignKey(User)

Comment: Are you asking about the code in models.py file?

Comment: No, for the third time, **I am asking about the code in 0003_question_user.py**. Why is that so hard to understand?

Comment: @DanielRoseman sorry for that and can you explain me why it would happen. What's the reason for the error? I have posted the text from file above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
#user = models.ForeignKey(User)
```

is commented now. 
Did you try to execute migrate while it was uncommented ?

try 
python manage.py migrate --fake 
and then

python manage.py migrate

Comment: Yes i did migrate when it was uncommented

Comment: Can you tell me why this error comes and can i add user field to this class?